# Python Telegram Bot answer

Tags: python, bots, telegram

How can I get response from Telegram bot and get some information to answer from local file? I wrote code below, but part with `current_status` doesn't work.

Could you please tell me why it doesn't work?

```py
import telebot
import requests

url = "https://link.com"
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Status" or "status":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, curl_request())

def current_status():
    with open('current_status.log') as file:
        status = str(file.readline())
        return status

def curl_request():
    resp = requests.get(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return("Available \n", current_status())
    else:
        return("Isn't available \n", current_status())

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

I mean, I getting answer from bot in Telegram just `Available` or `Isn't available` without text from my file which I open in `current_status` function.

Comment: what does write to this `current_status.log`?

Comment: @YasserMohsen just one string UPTIME -> 2023-01-14 09:48:36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.send_message()` takes text as its second parameter, but your function `curl_request()` returns tuple.

Can you try make it `return "Available \n" + current_status()`?